# "bsf" keyword in groovy scripting in java 

Tags: java, groovy

I'm using groovy scripting in java. Here is how it operates: I'm creating in java BSFManager, then register some beans, then I receive groovy script from the input and pass it for execution to BSFManager instance. There is something I don't understand. When I want to operate on class instances (beans) that I previously registered to BSFManager in my java code in my groovy script, I must use some special word 'bsf' to adress to BSFManager in my groovy script. E.g. `bsf.lookupBean("mybeanname")`. I didn't found any definition of that special word "bsf", but it seems to work. So what is the origin of that hidden `bsf` variable or where is it declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSF is short for *Bean Scripting Framework*, which is an Apache project for embedding scripting languages within Java applications.

The `bsf` object is created as part of that framework.

From the manual:

> Additionally, BSF declares an object named **bsf** within a scripting engine's execution context, which represents the BSFManager that is associated with the scripting engine. This object provides all of the methods and properties associated with the BSFManager to the script. However, the most used method within scripts is usually lookupBean(), which is used to access objects in BSF's object registry.

[The Apache Commons BSF manual](http://commons.apache.org/bsf/manual.html#Servlets_and_Other_Applications)